# How to make a page with a list of Users in a Salesforce Community?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

So I'm completely new to Salesforce Communities and working with the Experience Builder which is where I think this task would need to be done.

I want to display a list of Users in the Community (specifically only ones associated with the same Account as the current User) showing a certain set of fields and allowing in-line edits.

I see there's already a set of pages for User list, profile, and related list, but the User List page is blank by default.  I found the Record List component for Experience Builder, but it does not appear to support User.

I'm considering making a Lightning Component that displays my table of Users to then use as a component in Experience Builder, but I'm not sure how involved of a process that would be or if there is a more straightforward approach.

How can I go about making this?
(If it matters, when I first made the Community I believe I selected "Customer Service")